# TCP/IP using LWIP and FREERTOS

Tags: microcontroller, lwip

I want to allow a network communication  via TCP/IP using LwIP stack in FREERTOS. I am using  stm32f4 discovery board as my device with LCd interfacing and want to communicate with my pc. I am new to LwIP. Does anybody have source code or can hep me with any suggestions. Thank you

Comment: what does ST provide with the board/chip in question with respect to networking?  or are you adding this on?   what chip are you using, what network interface, what have you tried, where did it fail?

Comment: I enabled ethernet in RMII mode and lwip in stm32 cube. I set ip address for the device. Now how can i continue with it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a reference lwIP/FreeRTOS integration [in the FreeRTOS Interactive site](http://interactive.freertos.org/entries/20290712-FreeRTOS-Win32-project-with-lwIP-web-server) but note it is very old, and not all the code in it is relevant any more (for example it uses a pre-release of [FreeRTOS+CLI](http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Plus/FreeRTOS_Plus_CLI/FreeRTOS_Plus_Command_Line_Interface.shtml) that is not compatible with the released version).  Hopefully it will be useful to you as a template though.

There is also a FreeRTOS+TCP (not lwIP) [example for the STM32F4](http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Plus/FreeRTOS_Plus_TCP/TCP-IP_FAT_Examples_ST_STM32F407.html) which might provide a viable alternative - depending on your application - or at least provide you with a reference Ethernet driver that could be adapted for use with lwIP.